# sql LIKE nor returning rows expected

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

In mySQL I have the following WHERE clauses:

```
WHERE `candidates`.`availability` = "yes" 
AND `candidates`.`playing_age` LIKE "%child, 20's%"
```

In my database, I have a row in which the playing_age column looks like this,

> "child, teen, 20's"

Why would the LIKE in my WHERE clause not return this row, even though the row contains child and 20's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%   Matches any number of characters, even zero characters.

When you do `LIKE "%child, 20's%"` you are missing the `%` character between `child,` and `20's`. So, you need to add an extra `%`:

```
WHERE `candidates`.`availability` = "yes" 
AND `candidates`.`playing_age` LIKE "%child,%20's%"
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
WHERE `candidates`.`availability` = "yes" 
AND `candidates`.`playing_age` LIKE "%child,%20's%"
```

The result you want to be returned won't return because there was no wildcard in the middle of the string.

Answer (score 1):

This is not matching, should be

```
"%child, %20's%"
```

```
mysql> select "child, teen, 20's" like "%child, 20's%";
+------------------------------------------+
| "child, teen, 20's" like "%child, 20's%" |
+------------------------------------------+
|                                        0 |
+------------------------------------------+

mysql> select "child, teen, 20's" like "%child, %20's%";
+-------------------------------------------+
| "child, teen, 20's" like "%child, %20's%" |
+-------------------------------------------+
|                                         1 |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

However, your way of design the schema is quite no normalized,
split the child,teen,20's into three separate column (or 3 rows if using EAV),
and you can do comparison easily.

Answer (score 1):

LIKE "%child, 20's%" means : anything containing exactly "child, 20's".
leading % for "anything before"
trailing % for "anyhting after"

What would be more apporpriate for your seach would be

```
AND candidates.playing_age REGEXP ".*child,.*20's.*"
```

This would allow "matching of anything" between child & 20's

Note that leading & trailing .* might be removed and result still match. but not sure of the latter.